# New odometer needs adjusted

Tags: ford, ranger, odometer

2006 Ford Ranger - I changed the gauge cluster because there was an issue with the speedometer. The odometer never reset to the original miles. Its got a digital odometer. Gauges all work now, but the odometer is not correct. Can't justify purchasing a mileage correction tool because I'll only need it 1 time. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do about it:

1. Take it to a Ford dealership or other shop which has the odometer tool and have them reset the numbers.
2. Don't worry about. Just record what the old mileage was and disclose that number if you ever go to sell the vehicle.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into Forscan? Probably cheaper than paying a Ford dealership to program it for you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/70368)